# Do it exist a helper function how data_get (Laravel) in Django?

Tags: django, helper

The data_get function retrieves a value from a nested array or object using "dot" notation:

```
$data = ['products' => ['desk' => ['price' => 100]]];

$price = data_get($data, 'products.desk.price');

// 100
```

More detail in [Laravel Doc](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-data-get)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do this function:

```
def get_data(data, dot_path, default=None):
    arr_paths = dot_path.split('.')
    result = data

    for path in arr_paths:
        try:
            if isinstance(result, (dict, list, tuple)):
                result = result[path]
            else:
                result = None
        except KeyError as e:
            result = None

    if not result:
        result = default

return result
```